# @csv formatting without quoting entire line for lists containing only numbers?

Tags: csv, export-to-csv, jq

When trying to output lists using csv formatting, I end up with having quotes around the entire line. Is there a way to get rid of those just using `jq` without resorting to other tools? Example below:

I have a json string:

```
{"stat": {"foo": 1.2, "bar": 3.1}}
```

I apply the following jq command to it:

```
$ jq '.stat | [.foo, .bar] | @csv' test.json
```

The resulting stdout will be:

```
"1.2,3.1"
```

Now, I can fix this by applying a combination of `rev` and `cut`, but if possible, I would like to skip that step:

```
rev | cut -c2- | rev | cut -c2-
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the `-r` command-line option for "raw output".  As in: `jq -r ...`

p.s. If you ever find yourself having to lop off quotation marks from the beginning and ending of lines, that too can be done using jq. With jq version 1.4 or later:

```
jq -R -r '.[1:-1]'
```